# Authorization code for aspx and MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an application that uses both aspx pages and MVC controllers with actions.

A new feature requires an authorization check for incoming requests and redirecting them.

The application is deployed on different versions on IIS and primarily uses Windows and, in some deployments, cookie authentication. It is a one instance application (it runs from one server).

What is the best place to do it?

Ideally, I would like to avoid Application_AuthenticateRequest as it runs for all files (I could filter by file extension, I suppose).

The authorization check will require a service call -> db lookup, so most likely will have to cache it.

Answer (score 1):

`Application_AuthenticateRequest` is the correct place to do that if you are going to mix classic WebForms with ASP.NET MVC in the same application.